Is non-ionizing radiation actually dangerous?
The IAEA has done some research on how electromagnetic waves and says, "1.4. Exposure to radiation can also induce the non-lethal transformation of cells,
which may still retain their capacity for cell division. The human body’s immune
system is very effective at detecting and destroying abnormal cells. However,
there is a possibility that the non-lethal transformation of a cell could lead, after
a latency period, to cancer in the individual exposed".
That means that there must be some transformation of the cells. From what I see online, there is not much research done on the relationship between non-ionizing radiation and cancer.
In an WHO article, it states that "Epidemiological research examining potential long-term risks from radiofrequency exposure has mostly looked for an association between brain tumors and mobile phone use. However, because many cancers are not detectable until many years after the interactions that led to the tumor, and since mobile phones were not widely used until the early 1990s, epidemiological studies at present can only assess those cancers that become evident within shorter time periods. However, results of animal studies consistently show no increased cancer risk for long-term exposure to radiofrequency fields."
This means that there is an association between radio waves and brain tumors, but that is only for cellphones. WHO says cellphones emit 0.2 watts to 2 watts. So, for us operating 500 watts, shouldn't there be a greater risk for cancer? Is there more info online about this that I missed? Why hasn't anybody done any research about how harmful or not radio waves are?

Over the last 20 years cell phone power use has dropped enormously and has become dynamic.  I don't think studies including phones from 10 years ago can apply to today's phones, and I don't think any study less than 20 years long can show resulting cancers... in other words, I don't think these studies are relevant to today's phones nor can we do a valid study of such (yet).

The state of expert opinion is gathered by the ICNIRP in their publications. The papers referenced by their 2020 guidelines for RF exposure show that the risk from non-ionizing radiation is almost entirely due to heating effects.
Further, their references show that, while there are studies that show a link between cellphone use and cancer, the studies are a type of study called a "case-control" study, which inherently has wider error bands, and the link is within the plausible error band for that class of study (since the link is established by comparing the histories of people who've been diagnosed, rather than by monitoring to build up a history and then seeing whether those people get diagnosed over time). Studies that monitor cellphone use, and then look to see if you get diagnosed don't find the same link.

While the dangers of ionizing radiation are a problem, the dangers of non-ionizing radiation are obvious, well known, and frequently understated. Basically, nobody wants to be cooked, and nobody wants cataracts.
These undisputed dangers are much more likely and non-controversial.  We don't need to be distracted by these other proposed effects that have repeatedly failed to find any correlation let alone causation when we have known undisputed risks from the same cause.
Repeated burns can cause cancer just as much as ionizing radiation, but the burns are the real problem and in the short term more dangerous than the possible cancer.
These dangers are on the US amateur radio exams.  We are required to do environmental studies for our radiation for a reason.  And after you do your study, you know that you shouldn't transmit 500 watts with the antenna the same distance from you that you would expect a cell phone antenna.
